# What should the output layer of my NN look like?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, chess

I want to build a NN with keras that takes as input an image of a chessboard (may be taken from an angle) and that outputs for each of the 64 chess squares, if the square is 1) occupied by a white piece, 2) occupied by black piece, or 3) occupied by no piece.

I basically need some sort of 2D output from the NN, where each square has 3 possible outputs. How would such a NN look like in terms of design for the (output) layers? Is that even possible?

Comment: "each square has 3 possible outputs" You just described the output layer. Although I don't think you're looking for a 2d output unless you want a state being the output instead of just what's on a single square or not, as input.

Comment: The NN should output those 3 possibilities for each square not only for a single square. As it receives as input an image of an entire chessboard and not just a single square, wouldn't a 2D output be necessary?

Comment: Yes, if you want a state diagram.